# TypeError: validate_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

I am trying to override rest_auth's default LoginSerializer, when I try to login, it throws this error.
Here is my code:

settings.py

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'Customer.apis.serializers.LoginSerializer',
}
```

and Login Serializer

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def validate_email(self, email, password):
        user = None
        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email,
                                password=password)
        else:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError('Invalid Credentials')
        return user

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')
        user = self.validate_email(email, password)
        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

What could be the error? And the possible workaround?

Comment: `validate_email` method will only accept 1 parameter, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you name a method like `validate_<field_name>`, then it will be called during form validation(as per [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)) of that field, and only one argument will be passed through that method, which is the value of that field. So you need to rename it to something else. For example:

```
def verify_credentials(self, email, password):
    user = None
    if email and password:
        user = authenticate(email=email,
                            password=password)
    else:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError('Invalid Credentials')
    return user

def validate(self, attrs):
    email = attrs.get('email')
    password = attrs.get('password')
    user = self.verify_credentials(email, password)
    attrs['user'] = user
    return attrs
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've run into another problem. On changing it to validate_credentials, I'm getting a NOT NULL constraint failed: authtoken_token.user_id error. What could be wrong this time?

Comment: you need to add the full error stacktrace for that. Better if you ask a new question with that, because that is out of scope for the current question unfortunately. I will also recommend adding more code relevent to that error in new question. :)